# New relic (java) - Trace annotation does not trace inner methods

Tags: spring, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have this scenario. Method A is asynchronous and it's using method B and C, that are also asynchronous. @Async annotation is used by Spring to declare that method has to be runned in a new thread.

I'm using a @Trace annotation in method A. I would also like to trace methods B and C without using @Trace(dispatcher = true) on each one. Is it possible?

Trace annotation has a lot of flags, but I couldn't make it work.

```
@Trace(dispatcher = true)
@Async
public void methodA(){
     methodB();
     methodC();
}

@Async
public void methodB(){ //I don't want another @Trace annotation here
     //some code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As you've undoubtedly noticed, using `(dispatcher = true)` everywhere results in the creation of many small, disconnected transactions. The results may be difficult to understand in the New Relic UI.

The solution is to use New Relic's **[Java agent API for asynchronous applications](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/async-instrumentation/java-agent-api-asynchronous-applications)**. You can obtain a *token* from the Transaction created for `methodA()` and then *link* the token in both `methodB()` and `methodC()`.

It's important to *expire* the token after use, so you'll need to develop an application-specific scheme to get the token, pass it to each of the async executions that will link it, and then expire it.

Disclaimer: I'm a former member of the Java Agent team. I no longer work at New Relic. My opinions are my own and don't represent my current employer or anyone else.

Comment: I'm trying not to use New relic code inside my methods. Can the annotation @Trace(async=true) work here? What do you think?

Comment: I think you need calls to the API in this case. In fact, I neglected to mention in my response that you'll need the `@Trace(async=true)` annotation on `methodB()` and on `methodC()` _in addition_ to the API calls I described above.